# Is bool ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue(TKey, out TValue) method thread-safe?

Tags: c#-4.0, concurrency, dictionary, trygetvalue

It's not quite clear from this post: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/concurrentdictionarys-support-for-adding-and-updating/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Otherwise it would be useless, as this is a **thread safe** alternative to `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. See the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx:

> ### Thread Safety
>
> All public and protected members of `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` are thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads.